# How to get Vue Element.io working locally?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to download Vue [Element.io](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/installation) locally. If I am using example from CDN all works. But if I am linking to component placed on file system I am getting error.

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
```

I am getting error:

`Unknown custom element: <el-button> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

I tried to link with all package and part of it (single element like button). Thу error is same.

[image]

Comment: What's the full path to it's `index.js` starting from your project directory?

Comment: @dziraf I have add screenshot.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to import an ES6 module. If you're not using a bundler like Webpack, you'll want the same file they offer via the CDN link